# When and how should a wisteria be pruned?

Tags: pruning, wisteria

I just moved into a house which has two **well** established wisteria plants growing on the front of it.

To our knowledge, it's been here for about 30+ years and we'd like to get it under a little control with it being so thick.

You can see from the pictures that there is a lot of really thick, but seemingly rotten trunk at the base but this hasn't stopped the plants from growing quite vigorously...

Photos attached - we're in the North-West of England FWIW.

Any advice on what we can/should cut back, and when, would be greatly appreciated - also pointers to wisteria care - type articles...

[image: Trunk as it comes out of the ground]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]